# Is there a systematic way to construct a SUSY theory?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mathematical-physics, field-theory, supersymmetry

For the sake of simplicity, I am considering a 0+0d scalar field theory with multiple bosonic and fermionic fields/variables. The fields are coupled together up to a certain order (say 4) with coefficients such that the resulting Lagrangian is bosonic.

Is there a "necessary condition" for this theory to admit SUSY generators (in the sense that the lagrangian varies by a total derivative under the SUSY transformation)? And is there a systematic way to find all the independent generators?

Comment: Well, people have been supersymmetrizing these theories for 45 years by trial and error. For a *linear* representation of susy you need to have the right degrees of freedom matching fermions and bosons into supermultiplets, for starters, as you may have studied in your text. But, for *nonlinear* SSBroken ones, like Volkov-Akulov, your supermultiplets are reduced, and so no such restrictions obtain.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks. Do you have suggestions for introductory notes on this topic, perhaps focused on algebraic constructions of SUSY, particularly in low dimensions. I'm interested in using SUSY to study spin glasses (so 0+1d), like what Kurchan did, and trying to see what are all the possible SUSY dynamical equations one can write for a given spin model (similar in spirit to the static Landau-Ginzburg approach for ferromagnets).

Comment: Sorry, pedagogical literature ideas... There is a plethora of them...